# How to show pages on main category Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a project on Magento, and I have a weird problem. I have a main category, let's call it **Main 1**. And this main category has several sub categories. Let's call them **Sub1, Sub2, ...**.

**Main 1, Sub1, Sub2** have products inside. I have like 50 products in total for **Main 1**.

When I navigate to a subcategory, I have more products than I can see per page, so I have a pager.

[image]

But I don't know what happened on **Main 1**, that I can't see that pager. I have more products than I can see on **Main 1**, but I don't know what happened with the pager.

I suppose that there's been some change that I don't know on that main category, but I can't figure out which one.

So any ideas on how to recover that pager would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

This is my **pager.html**:

```
<?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

<?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
<div class="pager">
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($this->getShowAmounts()): ?>
<p class="amount">
    <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($this->getShowPerPage()): ?>
<div class="limiter">
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
    <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
    <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
            <?php echo $_limit ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
<div class="pages">
    <strong><?php echo $this->__('Page:') ?></strong>
    <ol>
    <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="previous<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?> i-previous<?php endif;?>" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">
                <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->canShowFirst()): ?>
        <li><a class="first" href="<?php echo $this->getFirstPageUrl() ?>">1</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
        <li><a class="previous_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getPreviousJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php foreach ($this->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
        <?php if ($this->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
            <li class="current"><?php echo $_page ?></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getPageUrl($_page) ?>"><?php echo $_page ?></a></li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>


    <?php if ($this->canShowNextJump()): ?>
        <li><a class="next_jump" title="" href="<?php echo $this->getNextJumpUrl() ?>">...</a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if ($this->canShowLast()): ?>
      <li><a class="last" href="<?php echo $this->getLastPageUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->getLastPageNum() ?></a></li>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php if (!$this->isLastPage()): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="next<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?> i-next<?php endif; ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getNextPageUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>">
                <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForNext() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?>
    </ol>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->getUseContainer()): ?>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The layout rendered was different for main categories!